# ERROR: "coalesce" is not a known variable in INTO clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.2, select-into

Following is my sample function

```
create or replace function samp(in a int) returns int as
$$
declare 
val int;
val1 int;
begin
select coalesce(a-1,1) into val,coalesce(a-2,1) into val1;
return val + val1;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

when executing it I get following error

> ERROR:  "coalesce" is not a known variable LINE 7: select
>   coalesce(a-1,1) into val,coalesce(a-2,1) into val1;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong - `into` is a single clause that applies to all the variables, not a keyword that should be applied to each variable:

```
SELECT coalesce(a-1,1), coalesce(a-2,1)
INTO   val, val1;
```

Comment: Huh. I never knew you could specify `into` multiple times, and have always used anonymous records. Nice.

Comment: @CraigRinger I am pretty sure you can't. It should be a single `INTO` clause. You can indeed have multiple targets, one for each select list item.